# How do I get the right amount of heat from Carolina Reapers in cookies/brownies?

Tags: baking

I want to bake some really spicy cookies/brownies. I've got some Carolina Reaper and I want to use them somehow to achieve a really hot flavor in cookies/brownies. I need to calibrate the heat level, so that it's the right level of really spicy. How do I do it?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to add a pepper to a cookie or brownie, or how to calibrate the heat level?

Comment: @Jefromi I want to calibrate the heat level, preferably with a Carolina Pepper. I know that I could simply use a sauce,but I want to do it with the pepper.

Answer (score 1):

Easy! You'll need to first make "Carolina Reaper powder"

1. Dry them by running a fishing line or thread near the stem and hang
   them in a dry place for 3 days.
2. Once they are dry, remove the stems and place in a [spice grinder](http://amzn.to/2hxDpZA) or food processor.
3. Place the powder in a [spice container](http://amzn.to/2hxDpZA).

One you have made your Carolina Reaper powder, you can proceed to make your brownies as normal, and add a pinch to the batter. The Scolville Units of your peppers will vary based on your plants vs someone else's, so it's difficult to recommend a precise amount of powder to use. That will also depend on how spicy you want these devil brownies to be!

To calibrate the right level of spiciness, this [jalapeno brownie](http://www.food.com/recipe/jalapeno-brownies-81562) recipe offers a good baseline. Based on some rough math, the recipe calls for 1 Million Scolville units. A single Carolina Reaper contains roughly 1.6 Million Scolville units. So you could use about 2/3 of one whole pepper, or you could use the amount of powder you get from 2/3 of a pepper.

EDIT: Based on some rough math below, approximately .04 dried peppers would be needed to accomplish the level of heat in the recipe above.

Comment: Are you suggesting calibrating by just guessing an amount of powder and baking a batch?

Comment: @Jefromi thanks for pointing out I didn't do a good job of covering that. I added a reference to my response that should cover it.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a little confused, though. The Scoville scale is roughly about concentrations, not absolute amounts of heat, so you need to take into account the size of the peppers, not just the ratings. Also, Wikipedia lists jalapeños at 1000-20000, not 1 million, but Carolina Reapers at 1.6 million as you've said.

Comment: That recipe uses 5 jalapenos and I assumed 10,000 per based on wiki and 6-8 Birds eye chilis, which I assumed roughly 150,000 per based on wiki, roughly totaling 1 million Scolville units. If Scoliville units are measued in heat/gram then we need to multiply the 1M Scollville by the mass of the jalapenos + birds eye. Say that's roughly 150 grams. So the recipe has 150M units of heat. If the reaper is 1.6M Scolville then we need 150M/1.6M grams of Carolina Reaper. So we need ~95 grams of Carolina Reaper. You could mess with the calculations a bit but that seems like a good starting place.

Comment: They're an approximation for heat per unit dry weight. (Note the *dry* part - it's based on drying the peppers then taking a unit weight of that powder.) You need to take that into account weight when you're combining the jalapenos and birds eyes, not after. Of course all of this is total guesses, since peppers vary and the scale isn't very rigorous.

Comment: That's ~70 grams of jalapenos and only 15-20 grams of birds eyes. If you assume that the water content of all the peppers is the same, so you can use the fresh weight (I'm not sure that's true...), then that's 70*10000+17.5*150000 = 3.3e6 scoville units * grams / unit weight. If the reapers are 5g (couldn't find a real number, but they're similar to habaneros), they'd similarly be 5*1.6e6 = 8e7 scoville units * grams / unit weight, so you'd need only 3.3e6/8e7 = 0.04 of a pepper to get the same heat as the jalapenos and birds eyes.

Comment: My math must be way wrong somehow because I intended to implicitly assume the fresh weight would be the same ratio as the dry weight for all the peppers. So somewhere I went wrong if I was off by a factor of 100! I edited my answer to include you 0.04 pepper answer as an approximation.